# Problems using POSITIONS and Code objects

Tags: raku

I am trying to create an object that implements `POSTIONS` for slicing

```
class Foo is Code { 
    multi method POSITIONS( Foo:D $foo: \pos) { 1,2 }
}; 
say <a b c>[Foo.new]
```

This errors with "Cannot make a Foo object using .new".

Making it a standalone object simply does not call POSITIONS:

```
class Foo { method POSITIONS { 1 } };
my Foo $foo .= new; 
say <a b c>[$foo] # No such method 'Int' for invocant of type 'Foo'␤
```

Main question here is: What are the conditions to get POSITIONS called to create a slice?

But also, the secondary question is: why can't `Code` objects be instantiated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that `Code` using `new` for object construction. It's a very base level class.  Per the [source code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/array_slice.pm6), what's actually needed is a `Callable`, and that's a simple role to apply any class.  Personally I would have expected it to call `CALL-ME`

For your second example, we can find

```
multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]>( \SELF, Any:D \pos ) is raw {
    SELF.AT-POS(pos.Int);
}
```

So if the type isn't contemplated in advance, it will just try to coerce to `Int` which your class doesn't have.

Your first one SHOULD work by simply changing it to

```
class Foo does Callable { 
  method POSITIONS(\foo) { 1 }
};
my Foo $foo .= new; 
say <a b c>[$foo]
```

However this errors, complaining that `Foo` doesn't implement `.pos`.  That function isn't documented in source that I can see *but* implementing it does make things magically work:

```
class Foo does Callable { 
  method POSITIONS(|c)   { (0,1,2,(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1,2),(0..2)).pick }
  method pos(|c)         { self.POSITIONS: c }
};
my Foo $foo .= new; 
say <a b c>[$foo]
```

The positional argument that's passed to `pos` is the list that's being sliced ( `(a b c)` in your example), in case you want to adjust the slice based on the array contents, `grep`/`map` style.

### Edit:

Actually, foolish me.  `pos` [was renamed to](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/ccf350e4bcf9a70f4038cb4259f82fc913dd87cd#diff-f4b5fbcbc7088093127b11d23e79918f) `POSITIONS` and TIO (that I was testing on) isn't updated.  Because of that change, I would recommend using both `pos` and `POSITIONS`, just calling `POSITIONS` inside of `pos` for anyone on older implementations.